# The functional equation $T(x\otimes y)=T(x)\otimes T(y)$ on certain $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Is there  a  name for the following property of  a $C^{*}$  algebra $A$?

$$A \simeq A \otimes A\;\;\; \text{The spatial tensor product}$$

Example of this situation is $A=C(X)$ where $X$ is the  Cantor  set or $A=\mathcal{K}$ where $\mathcal{K}$ is the algebra of compact operators on a  separable Hilbert space.

For any such $C^{*}$ algebra, after fixing an isomorphisms between the two algebras, one can consider the following functional equation

$$T(a\otimes b)=T(a) \otimes T(b), \;\;\; T(a^{*})=(T(a))^{*}$$
where $T$ is  a  linear operator on $A$.

> Does this imply that $T$ is a bounded operator?
>   Is there a  non scalar example of  such $T$ for $A=\mathcal{K}$, the algebra of compact operators?

Comment: Don't you think this could depend on the choice of isomorphism between $A$ and $A \otimes A$?

Comment: The property $A \cong A \otimes A$ is called self-absorbing. So-called strongly self-absorbing $C^*$-algebras have played a cornerstone role in the classification program.

Comment: btw. the only scalars that satisfy your condition are $0$ and $1$, since the first equation gives you $\lambda = \lambda^2$.

Comment: How do you define $T\otimes T$ on $A\otimes A$ without using boundedness in the first place? Remember that $A\otimes A$ is a completion of the algebraic tensor product and therefore you need some form of continuity to extend operators from the algebraic to the spatial tensor product.

Comment: @JohannesHahn  Thanks  for  your  comment. For two element $a,b$ $T(a)\otimes T(b)$ is defined simply as a "simple tensor", so I think that the definition does mot need bounded ness of $T$.Am I right?

Comment: @WillSawin Thank you for this very interesting point. Your comment is interesting and is a motivation to ask: How many isomorphisms between $\mathcal{K} $ and $\mathcal{K} \otimes \mathcal{K}$ are there?Some isomorphisms diffrent from "matrix tensor product?

Comment: @UlrichPennig thanks very much for your very helpful comment.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Well, yes for simple tensors this is a valid definition. But then you have only defined $t\otimes T$ on the *algebraic* tensor product which is a dense subspace of the/any C*-algebra-tensor product. You need some form of continuity to extend this maps from the subspace to the whole space.